# Table css overlap in new ios versions

Tags: javascript, css, ios, angular

I have a problem with tables on mobile.
On all devices they work fine except in new versions of iOS.
On Ios the table columns overlap, can anyone help me?

```
.cards-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 10px;
}
.product {
    width: calc(50% - 5px);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 3px 3px 20px;

    @include tablet {
        width: calc(33% - 5px);
    }
    
    @include desktop {
        width: calc(25% - 5px);
    }
}
```

[This is the normal result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64K2Z.png)

[This is the Ios result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnGwc.jpg)

This is the full code (Angular framework).

https://codepen.io/BattistiMatteo/pen/XWBwgKV

Comment: CSS on its own, tells us rather little. Please provide a proper [mre] of your issue, when asking this kind of question.

Comment: https://codepen.io/BattistiMatteo/pen/XWBwgKV